Can Magneto control and manipulate metal ores?
Magneto is the master of magnetism and by controlling and manipulating electromagnetic fields he can control various metals (including non-Ferro-magnetic ones).
Ore is a metal locked inside rocks via an Ionic bond with non-metallic elements. Ore has the metal-element atoms in it but not the metallic lattice structure.
My question is: Can Magneto manipulate metal ores? Can Magneto use his powers to extract the metal atoms of the ore and cast them into a metallic lattice that he can control?
In the film "X-Men: Apocalypse" Magneto uses his powers on the metal-rich soil and causes global catastrophe, after being influenced by Apocalypse himself.
This question may be related:
Is Magneto's power magnetism or can he manipulate all metals?

Semi-related, I've seen references to the X-Men Animated Series having Magneto building Asteroid M from ore-rich asteroids.

In a word, yes. Magneto can manipulate ores that are rich in metals.

House of Marvel #2 - Civil War
